# HowTo use my iPhone as WebServer?

Tags: iphone

Is there any people who deal with this issue?

My iPhone: 3G

PS: I'm asking this question, because in not so far future I want to buy new iPhone (3GS or 4G perhaps), and I don't know what to do with my old one. :)

PSS: Comments *"u can send it to me"* or *"just sell this old sh't"* will not be useful!)

Thank you!

Comment: a *wireless* webserver? I'm pretty sure you can come up with something better :P

Comment: It's BSD.  Jail break it, SSH to it, and try to compile things.  You'll have to use its wireless interface for network connectivity, as the AT&T network will not allow incoming connections.

Comment: Disagree with the close .. the specific question is can the iPhone be used as a **server**, which seems close enough to an allowable topic.

Comment: @tomjedrz Yes, I'm surprised to ...

Comment: This isn't the medium for hobbiest powerusers to contemplate their navel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a port of lighttpd in the cydia repository, but you'll have to jail break your Iphone to use it.